# Jupyter notebooks on Windows - using sparkmagic with kerberos

Tags: pyspark, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, kerberos

I'm having some difficulty with using Kerberos with sparkmagic on a jupyter notebook.  I installed jupyter via anaconda on a windows box, and I was able to set it up to access a test HDInsight cluster.  That was just to prove that I could get it to access anything via sparkmagic.  So I know the general jupyter/sparkmagic setup works.

What I really needed it to do was to talk to the on-prem cluster.  That is running livy and secured via kerberos.  My difficulty is in getting sparkmagic to use the windows kerberos tickets.  I can't find any directions on setting up the sparkmagic config file to authenticate.  Furthermore, when I run the following on windows, it gives me an authentication error when I connect to livy:

```
curl --negotiate --user myusername:mypassword --url http://livyserver:8998/sessions
```

If I run the same line when I ssh to the edge node, it authenticates properly.  I use the same username and password to authenticate Windows, the edge node and Hue.

In the sparkmagic config file, I tried putting in my username and password like so:

```
{
  ... stuff ...
  "kernel_scala_credentials":{
      "username":"myusername",
      "password":"mypassword",
      "url": "http://livyserver:8998",
      "auth": "Kerberos"
    }
  ... the rest is following example_config.json ...
}
```

So, how do I set up winkerberos and sparkmagic to honor the windows tickets?  Or is it that, despite using the same credentials, I need Windows to get a kerberos ticket from the authentication method used by the linux boxes?

Comment: By definition, Kerberos auth does not use login/pwd params. These are ignored. It uses the "tickets" available in the credentials cache for the current user on the current machine. Looks like your Linux machine generates your credentials automatically, try running `klist -e`. On Windows... It's complicated, Microsoft has its own flavor of Kerberos, and its own proprietary credentials cache, cf. `klist` from windows\system32 vs `klist` from your Java install.

Comment: BTW what do you mean by "winkerberos"??? Microsoft Active Directory and your PC use Kerberos; your Hadoop cluster and its KDC use Kerberos; but either that KDC is actually Active Directory, or it "trusts" AD, or it is completely separate and you will need custom tickets on Windows to authenticate on Hadoop.

Comment: @Samson Winkerberos is the Python module for python to interact with Windows' kerberos implementation.  It's implemented in python like this:

`try:
    import winkerberos as keberos
except ImportError:
    import kerberos`

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem?  I would like to know how you did, if so.

Comment: No, I didn't manage to solve it.  We punted and just developed a .jar file.  It made life a lot slower.